# reading variables from test case that has been declered in TestSuite

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit4, test-suite

Hello I'm struggling with a problem in my test automation project. The scenario is I have 2 test cases that are depended on each other, I run them in the suite and pass variables between cases via set and get methods. The problem comes in where I need to reuse this 2 test cases with different parameters in different suites, and to achieve that I need to initialize variable on the Suite level and try to access in the test script.

Example to try to explain it where my problem lies in.

this is the first TestSuite. (name of the test suite xxxDenyOutageRequestAsPA1)

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ CreateOutageRequest.class, DenyOutageRequestatPA1.class})

public class xxxDenyOutageRequestAsPA1 {

public static final String userName = "username";
public static final String Approver  = "(PA1)";

}
```

Then I access this variables in the test case like this.(I simplify the testcase as it is very long if i would copy and paste all test)

name of the test case is CreateOutageRequest

```
@Test
public void testBase() throws Exception {
    // Navigate to the page
    driver.get(baseUrl);
    //String userName = "QAORCreator";
    String userName = xxxDenyOutageRequestAsPA1.userName;
    String password = "password";
    String Approver = xxxDenyOutageRequestAsPA1.Approver;


    logIn.loginToOSS(userName, password);
    orRoutingPage.routeOutageRequestTo(Approver);
 }...
```

Now this is my second Suite (please note it using same testcase CreateOutageRequest) 
name of the test Suite is xxxDenyOutageRequestAsEG

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ CreateOutageRequest.class, DenyOutageRequestAsRegionalEngineering.class })
public class AllTests {

public static final String userName = "Engeneering";
public static final String Approver  = "PA2";
}
```

now the problems comes in, in accessing the variables that are in the different suite. even if they are the same name I need to specify the Suite name to get the variable data. can anyone think of any idea how to access this variables that are defined on the suite without specifying the suit name in the test case so i will be able to reuse test case in by the different suites? Or maybe I'm doing this wrong and there is a different approach to accomplish this task

Thank you all the help